# Salesforce Lead not created and Lead Id not returned when using Rest API?

Tags: rest-api, leads, salesforce2salesforce, remote-access, chrome

Hi guys i have been using **salesforce Rest Api** for logging and now i wanted to **create lead** using **access token** that is returned to me by the Login call. But when i try to create the lead using the access token it isn't created and the response i get doesn't contain a **Lead id**.

I have been stuck on this for days and after a lot of Googling i couldn't find an answer.

**I want to implement this functionality in android but for now i am using Google chrome Plugin Advance Rest Client for Testing.**

**Create Lead URL-->** `https://na14.salesforce.com/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead`

**Header -->**

```
Authorization: OAuth 00Di0000000Y4be!AR8AQHCnNzqTM1tItXuwTRdXfRmn7JbZlneSA3pMjmrw.5aZqz0JecaTj2coEXHbEi61iQEhHWg0lTc0BZ0k4U_1BccJvFaZ
```

**Payload or Body -->**

```
{"Phone":"789452",    

"Company":"Test Company",   

"Fax":"1238356"
,"LastName":"Micheal"

}
```

**Content-Type:** `application/json`

**I am using a post Request.
And the Response i am getting is**

```
    {
objectDescribe: {
name: "Lead"
label: "Lead"
keyPrefix: "00Q"
custom: false
labelPlural: "Leads"
layoutable: true
activateable: false
urls: {
sobject: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead"
describe: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/describe"
rowTemplate: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/{ID}"
}-
searchable: true
deprecatedAndHidden: false
createable: true
updateable: true
deletable: true
customSetting: false
feedEnabled: true
mergeable: true
queryable: true
replicateable: true
retrieveable: true
undeletable: true
triggerable: true
}-
recentItems: [8]
0:  {
attributes: {
type: "Lead"
url: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/--SomeId---"
}-
Id: "--SomeId---"
Name: "Luna, Wilredo"
}-
1:  {
attributes: {
type: "Lead"
url: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/--SomeId---"
}-
Id: "--SomeId---"
Name: "Rannga, Lite"
}-
2:  {
attributes: {
type: "Lead"
url: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/--SomeId---"
}-
Id: "--SomeId---"
Name: "Sith, Aro"
}-
3:  {
attributes: {
type: "Lead"
url: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/--SomeId---"
}-
Id: "--SomeId---"
Name: "Smith, Aberen"
}-
4:  {
attributes: {
type: "Lead"
url: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/--SomeId---"
}-
Id: "--SomeId---"
Name: "RANAHAN, MICHAEL"
}-
5:  {
attributes: {
type: "Lead"
url: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/--SomeId---"
}-
Id: "--SomeId---"
Name: "RABADI, RAED"
}-
6:  {
attributes: {
type: "Lead"
url: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/--SomeId---"
}-
Id: "--SomeId---"
Name: "A., Christopher"
}-
7:  {
attributes: {
type: "Lead"
url: "/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/--SomeId---"
}-
Id: "--SomeId---"
Name: "Ratnayake, Sam"
}-
-
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.I am posting the answer so that it may help those of you who are facing the same problem

What i was doing was that i was sending a login request as described in this [screenshot](http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/2131/fsso.png). And i was getting the following response.

```
{"id":"https://login.salesforce.com/id/00Di00000Y4EAC/005i0000000kAAA",
    "issued_at":"13756912686",
    "instance_url":"https://company.my.salesforce.com",
    "signature":"UAcaAbSj7vClbc/yAURGkT/7Hkjq6sllhcGvASs=",
 "access_token":"00Di0000000Y4befdjBiSvJ7RfW1s1fmUsLCf6UAQCgtmD.biS7T5rSOxyvtniyLeLN"}
```

I just changed the **creating lead Url** from

https://na14.salesforce.com/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead

to

**Format:**
instance_url+/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/

**Actual Url:**
https://company.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead/

Now everything works.The problem was that i had to concatenate the **instance_url** with the **lead Url**. I dont think i can create lead unless i know the instance to which API calls should be sent.

As mentioned in the [Salesforce Rest API documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/)

**instance_url: Identifies the Salesforce instance to which API calls should be sent**

Comment: Even if it expects some domain name then it should error out.But you got wrong response .Still cant believe why this happens .

Comment: I still suspect you used GET earlier than POST request

Comment: No i used post the problem was with the URL

Answer (score 0):

I just used the Create Call for my instance with the same code that you have  and works perfectly fine

workbench.developerforce.com

[image]

Please try using workbench and see if it works .I feel that you are definately
 missing and making a different API  call(I suspect you are debugging a  GET CALL request)

Also i suspect after creation you are redirecting to different GET request.

Comment: I am using         Authorization: OAuth 00Di0000000Y4be!AR8AQHCnNzqTM1tItXuwTRdXfRmn7JbZlneSA3pMjmrw.5aZqz0JecaTj2coEXHbEi61iQEhHWg0lTc0BZ0k4U_1BccJvFaZ        in the header. I am not logging into salesforce but using the above access token when sending create lead request. Why is it not creating lead this way?

Comment: How are you getting oauth token in advanced REST client?

Comment: here is a screenshot http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/2131/fsso.png   Sending this request returns me the access token. Which i use for further calls

Comment: ok did you try with workbench to see how service responds ?

Comment: yes using workbench I can create a lead. But the above access token method was working a few days back and now its not working :(

Comment: Workbench method is not what i require. I want to create a lead using access token

Comment: By any means anything got updated in your remote access in your org like the client secret or the ACCESS key.There is alternative way too debug this issue .http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.in/2012/12/oauth-20-salesforce-using-rest-console.html                                use chrome REST console .

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue in Postman while trying out APIs.
Fix: In Postman ,in API Settings, enable 'Follow Authorization header', 'Follow original HTTP Method' and 'Automatically follow redirects'